# Importing TimeStamp columns from excel to SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

As it often happens there is a lot of questions similar to this one, but none of the ones I found gives me an answer to the issue I am having.

I am trying to import columns with Timestamp from Excel to SQL DEVELOPER. In the Picture 1 you can see formatting of the dates in excel. Format RRRR-MM-DD GG:MM:SS is Polish equivalent of English YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
Picture 2 shows my NLS settings in SQL Developer and Picture 3 shows what i am getting while trying to transfer the data from excel. It looks like SQL somehow reads the format of the date on its own way? Or maybe excel stores the data in other way than its displayed while opening the workbook? Any ideas how to correct this?

[Presentation of my data arrangements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWLw8.jpg)

Comment: The format is wrong, try MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Minutes aren't MM but MI. As of your question: if nothing helps, load data into a VARCHAR2 column which will accept *anything*. Then move it to a DATE column using TO_DATE function with appropriate format mask.

Comment: The weird part is that importing the data as VARCHAR2 gives the same result, which is the date converted as MM/DD/YYYY - hours, minutes and seconds are gone. Any other ideas? I am beginning to think that maybe excel stores the data in some strange way that messes with the formatting, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured out what was the issue and I think it might be useful information for other users I will present the solution.

What helped me, was formatting the timestamp in Excel column as a text. Meaning it could not be neither number formatted as timestamp, nor a result of TEXT FUNCTION. It had to be a plain text. In attached screen you can se what I tried to do and the results in SQL DEVELOPER.

To make values in C column I copied and pasted as values Column B - it pastes those as a text and not as a numbers.

[Presentation of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdPcD.png)

Hope this will help someone in the future.